# Minecraft 1.14.3: Why are hostile mobs not spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing on a vanilla 1.14.3 smp server. At first, hostile mob spawns seemed normal; they would spawn out in the open during nights because I haven't lit up a whole lot of my island. Now they just downright won't spawn on the surface, even after I've lit up virtually every cave under my island. Most of the time I am the only one online, so it can't be that they are spawning near other players. Why are hostile mobs not spawning? Is the spawning broken somehow? The server is on easy, but as far as I know, as long as it's not on peaceful, the difficulty shouldn't affect standard mob spawning.

More details here (steps taken, screenshot, etc.): https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/ck40sc/hostile_mobs_not_spawning/[image: Here's one of my afk spots. Mobs won't spawn if I wait up here either.]

[image: I waited two Minecraft nights here and only got one spider.]
Oddly enough if I go to a friend's house several hundred blocks away (when he's online, but I'm not sure if him being online/offline matters here) mobs spawn at night normally.

Edit: my friend got off and I went to another area off my island and mobs seemed to spawn normally on the surface at night. It doesn't make sense to me that mobs won't spawn on my island because I lit up all the caves, so more should spawn on the surface at night instead.

Comment: Maybe a lot of mobs are somewhere else already, for example near a different player or in the spawn chunks. Try going to the spawn chunks, leave and rejoin. And are other players online?

Comment: Did someone do `/gamerule doMobSpawning false`

Comment: is it night? mobs can only spawn in dark places

Comment: @FabianRöling I have said "Most of the time I am the only one online, so it can't be that they are spawning near other players."

Comment: @Asadefa no, I still get the occasional mob spawn every now and then. Also the Reddit post has a screenshot of mobs not spawning at night. I think from my question here that it should be clear that I know they need darkness to spawn.

Comment: There probably are many monsters in that area there. You said in an edit that in a different area monsters spawn. So they probably unload when you're there. For example there could be a cave system with lots of zombies that picked up items.

Comment: @FabianRöling keepInventory is on. There should be very few, if at all, items for mobs to pick up. It's also on easy, so they shouldn't be able to pick up items at all. Since they don't have items they should despawn after 128 blocks, so I really doubt mobs in chunks that I've left are the cause.

Comment: I've seen a video once where there was a place for mobs to spawn, then to fall down far enough to fall down and for other zombies below to pick up their items. So after a long time, there was an army of zombies holding rotten flesh that lagged the entire server. Something similar might be happening to you.

Comment: As I have said, keepInventory is on and the server is on easy difficulty. There will be hardly any items on the ground and zombies shouldn't be able to pick them up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem that you're describing and from what I've found it's to do with the movement of the player (or lack of) that seems to prevent the mobs from spawning. I had the same issue where I could stand at the bottom where the mobs should be falling and I could leave it overnight and **NOTHING** would spawn. As soon as I ran up to the top of the tower and back down, oh look, there's 8 or so creepers falling to their death.

To fix your problem and allow you to AFK, build a powered rail that goes up to the top of your tower and then back down  that just loops. You should find that mobs start to spawn once you start moving around!